# Spring batch handle ConstraintViolationException

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using spring batch to import city data.

```
City{
  String name;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  State state;
}
State{
  String name;
  String code;
}
```

I have already populated required data in fieldSetMapper, in the processor, I need to set relation between state and city.

```
State state;
if ((state = stateDao.findByStateCode(city.getState().getStateCode())) != null) {
  city.setState(state);
} else {
  city.getState().setCountry(country);
}
```

Since spring batch using chunk to process transaction, so if multiple cities in the same chunk have the same state which state repository has not stored yet, it will cause a unique constraint violation.

For example, 2 city rows

```
{name:x, state:{name:xx,code:xy}}
{name:y, state:{name:xx,code:xy}}
```

When spring batch writes first row, it will create a new state with name xx and code xy. But for 2nd row, since that state is already in the database, it will throw `constraintviolationexception`. Is there a way to reprocess the 2nd row if an exception was thrown? The retry() will rollback also the first row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not fixed the problem, but I managed to avoid the problem by chunking one item a time instead 10.